# Speeding up Numpy Masking

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, masking

I'm still an amature when it comes to thinking about how to optimize.  I have this section of code that takes in a list of found peaks and finds where these peaks,+/- some value, are located in a multidimensional array.  It then adds +1 to their indices of a zeros array.  The code works well, but it takes a long time to execute.  For instance it is taking close to 45min to run if `ind` has 270 values  and `refVals` has a shape of (3050,3130,80). I understand that its a lot of data to churn through, but is there a more efficient way of going about this?

```
maskData = np.zeros_like(refVals).astype(np.int16)

for peak in ind:
        tmpArr = np.ma.masked_outside(refVals,x[peak]-2,x[peak]+2).astype(np.int16)
        maskData[tmpArr.mask == False  ] += 1
        tmpArr = None

maskData = np.sum(maskData,axis=2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** Memory permitting, here's a vectorized approach using [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
# Craate +,-2 limits usind ind
r = x[ind[:,None]] + [-2,2]

# Use limits to get inside matches and sum over the iterative and last dim
mask = (refVals >= r[:,None,None,None,0]) & (refVals <= r[:,None,None,None,1])
out = mask.sum(axis=(0,3))
```

---

**Approach #2 :** If running out of memory with the previous one, we could use a loop and use NumPy boolean arrays and that could be more efficient than masked arrays. Also, we would perform one more level of `sum-reduction`, so that we would be dragging less data with us when moving across iterations. Thus, the alternative implementation would look something like this -

```
out = np.zeros(refVals.shape[:2]).astype(np.int16)
x_ind = x[ind]
for i in x_ind:
    out += ((refVals >= i-2) & (refVals <= i+2)).sum(-1)
```

**Approach #3 :** Alternatively, we could replace that limit based comparison with [`np.isclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) in approach #2. Thus, the only step inside the loop would become -

```
out += np.isclose(refVals,i,atol=2).sum(-1)
```

Comment: Approach #1 wiped my memory immediately, but it would have been nice if it didn't.   #2 and #3 works great.  There is a drastic improvement. Thanks